# C++ multiple return values from thread using promise, future?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, promise, future

What I want to do is to return a value from each thread. However, it has this exception message.

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::__1::future_error: Operation not permitted on an object without an associated state.
```

The code looks like this.

```
vector<thread> t;
promise<class_name> promises;
vector<future<class_name>> futures;

for(int i = 0; i < NumberOfThreads; i++)
{
    futures.push_back(promises.get_future());
    t.push_back(thread(MyFunction ,i , pointList, std::move(promises)));
}
```

and the MyFunction looks like this.

```
void MyFunction(int index, const vector<Point>& pointList, promise<class_name>&& p)
{
....
p.set_value(classObj);
}
```

If I use a thread, then it works fine without exception message.

Any idea to solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't re-use the promise after you've moved it to its thread. Move the promise inside the loop body and your code should run fine:

```
vector<thread> t;
vector<future<class_name>> futures;

for(int i = 0; i < NumberOfThreads; i++)
{
    promise<class_name> p;
    futures.push_back(p.get_future());
    t.push_back(thread(MyFunction ,i , pointList, std::move(p)));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

When you do

```
std::promise<T> p;
```

you create a promise `p` with an *empty shared state*.  This is different from having *no shared state*.

When you move-from a promise, the shared state is taken.  So

```
std::promise<T> p2=std::move(p);
```

now `p` has *no shared state*, and `p2` has the *empty shared state* that `p` was constructed with.

When you `push_back` into a container, it does something analogous to the above construction (possibly repeatedly).

`p` is now an exceedingly useless variable.  It can be destroyed, or it can be assigned to, or it can be `swap`ed with another promise.  All other operations on `p` are illegal.

A function like:

```
template<class T>
void reset_promise( std::promise<T>& p ) {
  p = std::promise<T>{};
}
```

could be used to give `p` an empty shared state.  However, given the typical usage pattern of a `promise`, I don't see much point.

```
std::vector<std::thread> t;
std::promise<class_name> promises;
std::vector<std::future<class_name>> futures;

for(int i = 0; i < NumberOfThreads; i++)
{
  futures.push_back(promises.get_future());
  t.push_back(thread(MyFunction ,i , pointList, std::move(promises)));
}
```

on the first loop, you move out of the promise.  On the second loop, you try to `get_future` from a promise that was moved-from, and your code is doing something illegal.

Either:

```
for(int i = 0; i < NumberOfThreads; i++)
{
  futures.push_back(promises.get_future());
  t.push_back(thread(MyFunction ,i , pointList, std::move(promises)));
  reset_promise(promises);
}
```

if you really want to reuse the `promises` variable, or

```
std::vector<std::thread> t;
std::vector<std::future<class_name>> futures;

for(int i = 0; i < NumberOfThreads; i++)
{
  std::promise<class_name> promises;
  futures.push_back(promises.get_future());
  t.push_back(thread(MyFunction ,i , pointList, std::move(promises)));
}
```

will ensure you have a valid `promise` at the point where you use it.  The second is probably best in this case: promises are constructed, used, and discarded in a small scope.

Basically, `promise`s where made to be optimal for the create, extract future, move promise where it is needed, discard pattern.  Having a moved-from promise have a shared state would cost resources (as that shared state is usually stored on the heap), so they didn't do it.